# Bash: How do I "grep" output of ls -la matching file owner and file permissions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I'm working on a simple script that recieves a directory ex:"/var/www/" a user ex:"usr" and some permissions ex:"drwxr-xr-x" and has to show only the files/folders inside the directory owned by the selected user and only with the desired permissions. At the moment I'm doing something like:

where `$p` are perms and `$n` user

```
ls -alis "$d | grep $p | grep "$n"
```

where `$p` are perms and `$n` user

I know this is not the way to do it. How can it be done making sure it matches exactly with user and perms?

**PD: I want to avoid using "find"**

Comment: You could use regexp for thix.

Comment: Take a look at the `find` utility instead. It suits your needs better.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using "find" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this command:

```
$ find "$d" -user "$n" -perm "$p" -exec ls -alis \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d="/var/www/"
p="drwxr-xr-x"
n="usr"
ls -alis $d | grep "$p" | grep "$n" | awk '{print $11}'
```